# RTP/UDP Video Stream Via Local File?

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, video-encoding, udp, rtsp

I'm stumped here...

We use a signage software package here at work that for some weirdo reason, requires EVERYTHING to be coded in XML in order for anything to work...

The problem is this:

We need to show live feeds that are being streamed via UDP and now RTP as well. Within the pre-configured settings, is an XML file. Inside that XML file we have to add an 'address' to whatever 'file' we're wanting to broadcast, which is labeled under 'file properties' in the XML file. BUT we have zero clue as to how to get this to accept a RTP/UDP stream! When ever we try to just add the address for the streams, it says they can not be accessed. It appears that it thinks that the address we are putting in, is an actual file and not an address that can just be entered somewhere. Which doesn't makes sense......

I know this is rather application specific, but even the developers of the program don't know why we can't just throw in the RTP/UDP address and start going.

SO!

My possible solution, of which I need help with locating the specifics for... is that we need a file container of sorts. Think along the lines of having a file located on a hard drive that is technically just empty. That file could be something like Hey_this_is_a_stream.streamfile for all I care... That file, is basically 'accepting' a stream. As in, I could have it accepting a RTP/UDP video stream, and whatever program is accessing that file at that point in time, is thus 'seeing' the stream as if it were just a normal video.

I guess a better explanation would be:
-RTP/UDP stream is at 224.0.0.100
-File is set up so it looks for 224.0.0.100
-File maintains a constant 5 second cache from said stream
-A video player (like vlc for example) would open this file
-The video player sees the cached stream, and begins to play the cached content
-Because the file is constantly updated with new video data, the player never reaches the 'end' of the video and thus runs until there is no more video data provided to the file via the stream

I KNOW something like this exists SOMEWHERE... I've read a document written by some developer for Google who talked about the standard for it and talked in very high technical detail about the specifications and its use cases.. but never actually posted any sort of code or information on how a person can accomplish this...

Anyone know of anything that can do something similar to this?

I had thought about using VLC's 'stream to file' feature, which may work... But I know some video containers do not work for playback unless the file itself is 'closed'... kinda like CD's back in the day. Some players couldn't read a CD unless it was 'mastered' and thus 'closed' after files were added to it.

If no one knows of a program that does this specific thing, then does anyone know which sort of video container could be used open-ended so that I could just have VLC view the RTP/UDP streams and then stream it to a file, which could then be accessed by a different player to view what is currently being streamed?

Comment: A “stream” and a “file” use fundamentally different encoding and packaging. It is HIGHLY unlikely your approach would work without some form of intelligent on the fly conversion/translation of the packitsation structure.

Comment: What file formats does your signage support?

Comment: I have no clue exactly what all formats it can use honestly. I know it can play some pretty old things like quicktime formats... and mp4. I am not the one with access to the actual content manager. But was 'tasked' with figuring out 'how it works'... which kinda seems like a flawed idea there... figure out how something works, without having direct access to it. yay!

Comment: And while yes a stream and a file are different, it is possible. Using OBS I was able to open up a both a Twitch.tv stream and the locally broadcasted udp racing stream, then told it to save to a local .m4v file. While it was recording either of those two streams to the file, I was then able to open the file up in VLC and BOOM there was the stream playing with only a 10 second-ish delay. Now every time you open the file, it plays from the beginning, but hey! I'm at least going down the path here. Now to get access to the content manager and see if it'll work there!